# How to pass ajax result as parameter to another ajax to make a request

Tags: javascript, ajax, loops

I want to pass ajax result id to another ajax so that it can call the other endpoint. I need to first get the id and name of the fund. then pass is back to another endpoint to get the actual price and display to users.

So users can see the price at real-time.

I have been able to display the names not to pass the id back is the challenge I am facing now.

```
 <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="text-center funds-item-container">
                <h3>Get Prices</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({  
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://datarecapture.premiumpension.com:8089/api/Prices/GetAllFundNames',
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function(resp) {
            console.log('hello: results', JSON.stringify(resp))


              for (var i = 0; i < resp.result.length; i++) {
                console.log('hello: results', JSON.stringify(resp.result[i].FUND_NAME));


                $('.funds-item-container').append(
                   `<div><h5>Price ${i+1}</h5>
                      <a id='#price${i+1}'>
                       <a href="${resp.result[i].FUND_ID}"> ${resp.result[i].FUND_NAME}</a>
                      </p>
                    </div><hr>`
                );
              }
            },

            error: function(xhr, status, error){
              debugger
               var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
               alert('Error - ' + errorMessage);
            }
    });




    $.ajax({  
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://datarecapture.premiumpension.com:8089/api/Prices/GetCurrentFundPrice?fundId=' + ${resp.result[i].FUND_ID} ,
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function(resp) {
              console.log(resp);


             for (var i = 0; i < resp.result.length; i++) {
               //console.log('hello: results', JSON.stringify(resp.result[i].FUND_NAME));


                $('.funds-item-container').append(
                   `<div><h3>'</h3>
                      <a id='#price${i+1}'>
                       ${resp.result[i].FUND}
                      </p>
                    </div><hr>`
                );
          }
            },

           // error: function(xhr, status, error){
           //   debugger
           //    var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
           //    alert('Error - ' + errorMessage);
            })
    });


 </script>
        </body>
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the code as JavaScript function in a separate .js file and call that function from the html page. Then inside the function you can call other functions that will perform other ajax requests.

Answer (score 0):

you can use callback fun to call another API end point

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="text-center funds-item-container">
            <h3>Get Prices</h3>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({  
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://datarecapture.premiumpension.com:8089/api/Prices/GetAllFundNames',
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(resp) {
        console.log('hello: results', JSON.stringify(resp))


          for (var i = 0; i < resp.result.length; i++) {
            console.log('hello: results', JSON.stringify(resp.result[i].FUND_NAME));
                callbackfun(resp.result[i].FUND_ID)

            $('.funds-item-container').append(
               `<div><h5>Price ${i+1}</h5>
                  <a id='#price${i+1}'>
                   <a href="${resp.result[i].FUND_ID}"> ${resp.result[i].FUND_NAME}</a>
                  </p>
                </div><hr>`
            );
          }
        },

        error: function(xhr, status, error){
          debugger
           var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
           alert('Error - ' + errorMessage);
        }
});




});

 function callbackfun(resp)
{
    $.ajax({  
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://datarecapture.premiumpension.com:8089/api/Prices/GetCurrentFundPrice?fundId=' +resp ,
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function(resp) {
              console.log(resp);

             for (var i = 0; i < resp.result.length; i++) {
               //console.log('hello: results', JSON.stringify(resp.result[i].FUND_NAME));


                $('.funds-item-container').append(
                   `<div><h3>'</h3>
                      <a id='#price${i+1}'>
                       ${resp.result[i].FUND}
                      </p>
                    </div><hr>`
                );
          }
},

            });
}

</script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks. The response is showing in the console now. But I need to show each unit price under their name. Sorry I am asking this

Comment: you can create a table with fund id as id and push data into it