# Call second JavaScript function with getJSON after first one is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, function, asynchronous

I have multiple functions with `getJSON` in it. Can I call/load the second function after the first one is loaded?

Right now the second function is called first and then the first one is loaded. Is there anyway for me to finish loading the first one and then call the second one.

My JavaScript

```
const functionOne = () => {
   $.getJSON(api, api_result => {
      $.getJSON(api2, api2_result => {
         build Highcharts
      });
   });
}

const functionTwo = () => {
   $.getJSON(api3, ap3_result => {
     build Highcharts
   });
   $.getJSON(api3, api3_result => {
     ...doSomething
   });
}

functionOne();
functionTwo();
```

Right now `functionTwo()` is loading first (highcharts being drawn) and then `functionOne()` is being loaded since getJSON is asynchronous. Is there anyway to draw my highcharts in `functionOne` first and then moving on to `functionTwo`?

Comment: Have a look at [`promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) or the jQuery [`deferred`](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

Comment: have a look at this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57934513/how-to-pass-ajax-result-as-parameter-to-another-ajax-to-make-a-request/57934663?noredirect=1#comment102285917_57934663

Comment: `$.getJSON(api3, ap3_result => {
     buildHighcharts; 
   $.getJSON(api3, api3_result => {
     ...doSomething
   });
   });` or put the second get at the end of buildHighcharts

Comment: While `promises` are the correct answer, a simpler, potentially easier to understand option is to pass in a callback:  `functionOne(functionTwo);`  then `function functionOne(whenDone) { $.getJSON(api, function() { buildhighcharts(); whenDone(); }}`

Comment: Neither of the currently existing answers wait for `api2` before invoking `functionTwo`, so be careful...

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Something like the following?

```
const functionOne = () => {
   $.getJSON(api, api_result => {
      $.getJSON(api2, api2_result => {
         build Highcharts
      });
   }).done(function() {
    functionTwo()
  })
}

const functionTwo = () => {
   $.getJSON(api3, ap3_result => {
     build Highcharts
   });
   $.getJSON(api3, api3_result => {
     ...doSomething
   });
}

functionOne();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using async/await, you can be sure the content of the second section is executed only on completion of functionOne

```js
async function functionOne () {
   await $.getJSON(api, async function(api_result) {
       await $.getJSON(api2, api2_result => {
         build Highcharts
      });
   });
}

async function functionTwo () {
   await $.getJSON(api3, ap3_result => {
     build Highcharts
   });
   await $.getJSON(api3, api3_result => {
     ...doSomething
   });
}

functionOne().then(functionTwo);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

While promises are most likely the "best" approach for this, they can take a while to become proficient in - in this case there's already a nested ajax call, which certainly complicates matters.

A simpler, potentially easier to understand, option is to pass in a callback:

```
function functionOne(callbackWhenComplete) {
   $.getJSON(api, api_result => {
      $.getJSON(api2, api2_result => {
         build Highcharts

         // Call callback, when everything else is complete
         callbackWhenComplete();
      });
   });
}

const functionTwo = () => {
   $.getJSON(api3, ap3_result => {
     build Highcharts
   });
   $.getJSON(api3, api3_result => {
     ...doSomething
   });
}

functionOne(functionTwo);
```

Couple of points to note:

- It's `functionOne(functionTwo)` *not* `functionOne(functionTwo())`

so you're passing `functionTwo` function itself as the callback, using `functionTwo()` will call functionTwo first and the pass the result

- you could/should check if `callbackWhenComplete` has been passed, eg use

`if ($.isFunction(callbackWhenComplete)) callbackWhenComplete()`

- you probably want a better variable name than `callbackWhenComplete` (just for examples)